# ASP.Net is not working properly on IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, host

I have an Visual Studio 2010 ASP.Net project. And I want to deploy this project to the my host. I did but my site is not working properly. I can access to Home Page etc. but I can not do my prior job. I have to change some word template which located on the server. I am using IIS 6. Thank you.By the way I did change some access property but it did not work.

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Here is the stack trace

```
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).]
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType) +0
System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType) +79
System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj) +76
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
TemplateModify3.modifyCont.justDoIt() in C:\Users\q\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TemplateModify3\TemplateModify3\modifyCont.aspx.cs:120
TemplateModify3.modifyCont.runDelegate(myDelegate dlg) in C:\Users\q\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TemplateModify3\TemplateModify3\modifyCont.aspx.cs:92
TemplateModify3.modifyCont.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\q\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TemplateModify3\TemplateModify3\modifyCont.aspx.cs:72
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.onclick(EventArgs e) +118
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Comment: What is line 120 in the file `modifyCont.aspx.cs`?

Comment: that page try to change word templates in server @Filip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an security issue with COM libraries with Windows Server2008 R2. This security issue prevent to use COM libaries with Server 2008 R2. If the server was 2003 version, it coul be work.

Answer (score 1):

Try chaning the user that runs the Application Pool, it seems that you are trying to access some `COM` objects that your IIS_USR don't have access too.

You can also try using [`Impersonation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: How can i give access permissions to the COM objects.

Comment: How can i give access permissions to the COM objects. @Filip

Comment: @Güngör, did it work when using Impersonation / Change user for Application pool? You might find this usefull: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325791

Comment: I tried but it did not help me. I thought I can not use Word dll s on my server @Filip

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a third party dll like Crystal Reports that may not be installed correctly or at the correct version? It could be that said third party dll is trying to access the windows or .net temp folders or a related dll that does not exist.

Comment: Yes I am using word dll s on my project. But I install word 2010 on my server but it did not work.

Comment: Yes I am using word dll s on my project. But I install word 2010 on my server but it did not work. @Fellmeister